# Using compilation-mode to parse error stacks, relocating them

Tags: compilation

I run several applications, in several languages, that store their error stacks
locally.  I made a small emacs mode that allows me to browse those errors and
navigate the related code.  The code I wrote, at its core, is basically loading
those stacks from the database in a buffer and setting that buffer in
compilation code.  Then I can browse code by using `previous-error`,
`next-error`, etc. to navigate the code.  `compilation-mode` is great because it
knows many error regexps so I don't need to deal with them (I add to add just 3
new regexps to local variable `compilation-error-regexp-alist`)

Very convenient and that has been working fine for years.  The paths of the
stacks are absolute, which suits fine to compilation mode.

But more and more I run those applications in lightweight containers.  Then, the
path of those stacks does not works because I have mounted the container
filesystem in different paths in my host (I run emacs exclusivelly in the host,
and I store the stacks there).  Then, emacs cannot find the path the files are
and I cannot browse them.

I mount the root filesystem os my containers in known locations.  So, for a
stack /a/b/c/d.c:80 in container "foo", I can calculate the path very easily:
/containers/foo/a/b/c/d.c:80

I tried to use `compilation-search-path`, with no avail (`compilation-find-file`
does not concatenate an absolute path to the elements of the search path, only
the basename)

I would appreciate some hint of how to achieve what I want (basically smarting
`compilation-find-file` to prepend a path to those paths in its "error lines")
that does not violates compile.el encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, I ended up solving it via defadvice (it is a hackish solution imho).  When browsing the stacks, I set the value of a local variable (`container-path`) to the container path of that specific stack and then I have the following defadvice:

```
(defadvice compilation-find-file (around relocate-to-container (marker filename directory &rest formats) activate)
  (if (and container-path (file-name-absolute-p filename))
      (let ((filename (concat container-path filename)))
        ad-do-it)
    ad-do-it))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to use an old hack in compile.el:

```
(setq-local comint-file-name-prefix "/containers/foo/a/b/c/d.c:80")
```

This was meant originally for use inside rlogin.el buffers (i.e. a remote shell), but your situation is basically the same.

You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask for its name to be fixed since it really doesn't have much to do with comint.

Comment: Sadly, that does not work.  In `compilation-find-file`, there is an `(if (file-name-absolute-p filename) ... (setq filename (file-name-nondirectory filename))` that strips the directory part.  I need the full absolute path to be appended to `/containers/foo`

Comment: Then you should report this via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.